# What's standard practice for user configuration of a project using only Make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

What's standard practice for user configuration of a project using only Make?  Specifically, I'd like to know how what's normally done to have the user communicate things like library and install locations without using a utility like autotools or CMake.  I've seen some projects leave certain variables blank in the Makefile that are filled in by the user.  This feels nonideal in the sense that if the Makefile itself is under version control, this will register as a change and one that's likely should not be checked in.  It also makes it awkward to have multiple configurations lying around.  It seems like there should be a way to have an external configuration file with the possible flags for the user to change, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this or whether it's normal practice.

---

### Edit 1

Alright, this is one attempt at the goal, but I'm still interested in whether there's a better way to do this.  For the Makefile

```
ifndef CONFIG
ifeq (,$(findstring config,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
$(error Usage: make CONFIG=<configuration> or make config)
endif
else
include ${CONFIG}
endif

all:
    $(info Name is $(Name))
    $(info Age is $(Age))
    $(info Profession is $(Profession)) 
    @:

.PHONY: config
config:
    $(info Name :=)
    $(info Age :=)
    $(info Profession :=)
    @:
```

Then, running `make` gives

```
Makefile:3: *** Usage: make CONFIG=<configuration> or make config.  Stop.
```

Running `make config` gives

```
Name :=
Age :=
Profession :=
```

Ostensibly, we run something like `make config > bob.config` and then fill in details such as

```
Name := Bob
Age := 23
Profession := Carpenter
```

Then, running `make CONFIG=bob.config all` gives

```
Name is Bob
Age is 23
Profession is Carpenter
```

This more or less does what I want, but, again, I'd like to know if there's a better or more standard way to handle this.

Comment: I think that you may be a possible user of the [GNUmake table toolkit](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt). If you can accept that you are using a library of functions on top of pure GNUmake, I am quite certain that you can use that as a viable method of Config Management.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've some choices.

First: you create some include files with different parameters/options and `make` will include depends on a param:

```
# Makefile
ifdef v1
include vars.v1
endif

ifdef v2
include vars.v2
endif
```

If you want `v1`: `make -Dv1`.

Second: you include the definitions into `Makefile`:

```
# Makefile
ifdef v1
destdir=...
flags=...
endif

ifdef v2
destdir=...
flags=...
endif
```

Third: you'll pass your parameters via CLI but I think it's complicated if you've many parameters (maybe you can use shell scripts or aliases).